# HTML CSS - Landing page background-image position

Tags: html, css, image

I create a landing page for myself. Texts and background images.

Unfortunately, at lower resolutions (e.g. 1200x800) image is cut off.

I position the text with paddings and I can see that they affect the images. Is there any way to position this photo correctly?

I tried with background-position but then the photo sometimes covers the text (on lower resolutions). Font size, media rules - I tried.

Is there any way to fix it? Other text positioning? Another parameter for the background?

Greetings.

```
<div class="block">
  <p class="content"><span class="big">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="small">
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br>
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br>
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br>
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br>
      Lorem ipsum.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

```
.block {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/lookpol/lookpol1603/lookpol160300012/55394889-butterfly-on-right-side-of-white-background-.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 15vw;
    padding-bottom: 15vw;
}

.big {
    color: black;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.small {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6471w5t9/

Comment: Would be be able to add an explanation of what you want the page to look like. Does the BG image need to be in the container div or can it be the body background? Are you planning on having the image scroll up or will it be a fixed background? Do you need that entire image with watermarks or is it just the butterfly you want positioned on your page?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `background-attachment:fixed` to your block class

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try background-size: contain; to your block class

Answer (score 0):

try adding background-size:100%; to the container element